# popup layout not centered in Gingerbread device

Tags: android, android-layout, popup

I have a problem with a custom layout.

When running it on emulators, the popup adjusts itself to the size of my custom layout, yet when I run it on my Atrix, this happens:

[image: Picture]

As you can see, the layout is not centered.

Now, this is my custom layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtVersus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/popup_unlock"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPopup"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/imagen_config_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/imagen_config_height"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/char_cersei"/>

<net.rahl.rahlutils.CustomFontTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPopupName"
    style="@style/ConfigText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

<net.rahl.rahlutils.CustomFontTextView
    android:id="@+id/txtPopupCasa"
    style="@style/ConfigText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnCerrarPopup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:text="@string/ok" />
```

And this is my part of the code where I set and show it:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(con);
dialog.setTitle("Felicidades!");
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.unlockdialog);
((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgPopup)).setBackgroundResource(con.getResources().getIdentifier("char_" + name.toLowerCase(), "drawable", con.getPackageName()));
((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtPopupName)).setText(name);
((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtPopupCasa)).setText(casa);
((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCerrarPopup)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        dialog.cancel();
    }

});
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show();
```

Do you know how to fix this?